# Solving system of nonlinear equations via iteration

Tags: algorithms, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

I will give an example to illustrate the question:

Assume I have the system:

$$
xy + x + y = 7\\
x^2 + y^3 = 9
$$

and I want to solve for $x$ and $y$. It is a fairly common approach to rearrange the first equation for $x$ and the second for $y$ as follows:

$$
x = \frac{7 - y}{1+y}\\
y = (9 - x^2)^{\frac{1}{3}}
$$
then to choose a pair of starting values $x_0,y_0$ and iterate between these until (hopefully) the results converge on a solution.

For this example the solution does converge to $x = 1.91$ and $y = 1.75$ after about 15 iterations (starting with $x_0 = y_0 = 1$) and these values are indeed solutions.

My questions are:

1) When will this approach be successfull? Can we know a priori if it will be likely to work or not work on a given equation set.

2) Why does it work at all, is there any underlying theory which has been developed to understand the convergence of these schemes which iterate through a given equation set?

3) Does this approach and area have a specific name? (More specific than just 'solving systems of nonlinear equations').

Comment: Why don't you solve the first equation for x and plug it into the second equation and then use Newtons Method? Or you could directly apply Newtons method to the Vektor equation.

Comment: @MrYouMath The example itself was just to illustrate the method of iterating through the equations. You could do as you suggest in this example but not in a more complicated example where none of the variables can be explicitly solved for. You can also directly apply Newtons method as you suggest, but my question was not about that but about the iteration approach described. I am interested because the iteration approach crops up a lot in engineering and other applied sciences and I have become interested in why and when iterating works.

Comment: Sorry, didn't read the full question. This method that you describe looks very similar to a fix point iteration.

Comment: @MrYouMath You're right! This is just fixed point iteration of a vector valued function of two variables. Thanks :)